# Индикатор урона

Tags: разработка-игр

Во многих играх видел индикатор урона, который показывает с какой стороны игрок получил урон. Есть еще подобная система, когда враг игрока находится за пределами экрана, то указатель на экране показывает в какой стороне от игрока враг. Подскажите каким образом это реализуется? Ну или хотя бы как это называется, чтобы знал в какую сторону копать)

Comment: обычно с помощью [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)

Comment: Есть координаты (квадрат, но не всегда) камеры (экран), есть координаты врага и координаты игрока. По формуле зная все координаты это можно вычислить.

Comment: @nick_n_a а не подскажешь по какой формуле?)

Comment: определись - ты в данном вопросе спрашиваешь либо про индикатор урона, либо про определение местоположения игрока